# Ubuntu syntax - 'zfs' vs 'zpool'

Tags: command-line, 20.04, zfs

Ubuntu/Zfs newbie.  I'm trying to setup zfs on a new ubuntu 20.04 install. While going thru countless webpages I noticed that some commands used 'zpool' while others used 'zfs'. I also came across two ubuntu manual webpages that appear to indicate two sets of commands:

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/zfs.8.html

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/zpool.8.html

My question is are the commands inter-changible or are they addressing different sets of commands?

Comment: Maybe you should read something like https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2020/05/zfs-101-understanding-zfs-storage-and-performance/ to get started on understanding zfs

Answer (score 2):

They are not interchangeable, they have no functionality overlap. zpool is used for pool level operations, zfs is used for file system and volume level operations.